# Complex mysql query issue

Tags: php, mysql

Im currently working on a live search and ran into the following problem:

The following query works but i would rather gather "topic" and "threadid" columns from table "bb1_threads" and only column "message" from table "bb1_posts"

```
SELECT posttopic AS topic, threadid FROM bb".$n."_posts WHERE message LIKE '%$search_string%' OR posttopic LIKE '%$search_string%' LIMIT 1
```

The following query also works but i cant search the field "message" from table bb1_posts this way:

```
SELECT topic, threadid FROM bb".$n."_threads WHERE topic LIKE '%$search_string%' LIMIT 1
```

So what i would like to have and tried to build for hours is a query that:

- selects field "threadid" and "topic" from table "bb1_threads"
- searches field "topic" in table "bb1_threads"
- searches field "message" in table "bb1_posts"
- Sorts the results by best match. (If the search result is closer to the string in column "message" than use that, otherwise the search result from "topic" should be used)

If someone could post a ready to use query, i would really appreciate that!
Merry Christmas :)

Comment: Is there a relation between the 2 tables? Maybe using a `join` would resolve the issue? Variables also should not be in SQL, bind values into query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work.

1. search `bb1_posts` by `message` and assign `1` as `search_rank`
2. search `bb1_thread` by `topic` and assign `2` as `search_rank`
3. union results from both, order by `search_rank` and pick the first row

```sql
select threadid  as threadid,
       posttopic as topic,
       1         as search_rank
  from bb1_posts
 where message like '%$search_string%'
 union all
select threadid  as threadid,
       topic     as topic,
       2         as search_rank
  from bb1_threads
 where topic like '%$search_string%'
 order by search_rank
 limit 1;
```